# how to run Langage C code in a AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I looking for documentation on official AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/?nc1=h_ls

I find this:

**Q:** What languages does AWS Lambda support?

AWS Lambda natively supports Java, Go, PowerShell, Node.js, C#, Python, and Ruby code, **and provides a Runtime API which allows you to use any additional programming languages to author your functions**. Please read our documentation on using Node.js, Python, Java, Ruby, C#, Go, and PowerShell.

I do not find this documentation API. I want find a simple programme read/write file in langage C. after I will want expose after a API gateway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions to that:

1. Develop your own [custom lambda runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html) for that. AWS provides some guides and examples of how to do it for C++ in [Introducing the C++ Lambda Runtime](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/)

- Use [lambda container images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) which allow you to run docker containers (properly prepared) for your function.

Comment: thank you for your answer but all sample are for C++ (git clone https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp.git). I need re-use a legacy Langage C code.

Comment: @StéphaneGRILLON Well, "custom" means that you have to develop it yourself. It may not exist in a public.

Comment: I understood "custom", that's why I ask on stackoverflow if anyone has an example with the langage C.

Comment: I see aws-lambda-cpp project. Is it complexe but work for langage C. thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/PauloMigAlmeida/aws-lambda-c-runtime for a working example